# Getting n number of words on either side of a particular word in a sentence

Tags: java, string

I need to extract context words on either side of a particular word in a string. The particular word in this case pertains to a proper noun in the string. E.g.

I love the cakes Martha bakes as they are so delicious!

In this case Martha is a proper noun and I would like to extract say 4 words on either side of Martha to be able to classify Martha as a name, location or organization. In this case bakes is my clue that Marth is a person. I was looking at a window size of 4 but what in the cases where there are fewer than 4 words on either side of the target word or what if its the  first word of the sentence.

So essentially:

1. I'd like to get 4 words on either side of the target word.
2. Put them in two separate lists called leftWords and rightWords
3. Check to see if there are fewer than 4 words then reduce the window size and get whatever number of words are available on either side.

Comment: Do you have any actual code?

Comment: Please provide what you tried so far, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do have code but the way i am doing it currently is by using nlp tools to get chunks out of sentences and getting context words from chunks. But in most cases I realized that proper nouns get split into their own chunks hence don't have any context words. SO I decided to try extracting context words from the entire sentence using windowing.  So I don't really have valid code to share. Sorry about that. Just an idea about how to make the window flexible would do.

Comment: It depends a lot on your more exact requirements. What constitutes a word? How should punctutaion be handled? Is `leftWords` a list of words or a list of subsentences of for example 4 words? I also don’t understand how you identify the proper name. Also, does item 3 mean that if there are only two words before “Martha”, you also want only two words after? And the other way around?

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm using POS Tags to identify proper nouns. You make a good point...context words pertaining to each proper noun should be a single entry. I'm thinking a map with key as the proper noun and values as left and right words. As far as words are concerned I'll take whatever words are available upto my window size on either side. So if there are 3 words on the left and 4 on the right then I take the 3 and the 4. No of left words should be independent of right words and vice versa. All I need is help with the making this sliding window size flexible. The rest I can figure out.

Comment: @OleV.V. Also taking into account that a sentence could have more than 1 proper noun. But that shouldn't affect the windowing as I will have the start and end index of the proper noun

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have the start and end indices of the relevant proper name (in the case of `I love the cakes Martha bakes as they are so delicious!` I think they will be 17 and 23).

A suggestion is you take out the parts of the sentence before and after the proper name in two substrings, then use regular expressions to match the desired number of words. In our example, the substring before `Martha` is `I love the cakes`, and the regular expression `\S+(\s+\S+){0,3}\s*$` will match up to four whitespace-delimited words at the end of this substring (in this case it will be the entire string, but if there were more words, it would only be the last four). You will have to subtract 1 from the desired number of words and fill in the result where the 3 is in the expression.

I trust you to do similarly for the words after the name.